# Finding repeated code in a file and print those repeated codes to another file

Tags: java, file-io

I'm want my program to read/search a .dat file for multiple codes*(Ex: phone numbers with the same 6 digit as 240-667-XXXX)* and I want to print those codes to new .dat file. I seem to be stuck and when I try to search for things to help me, i doesn't seem to work. If you can help, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {
        BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("file_1.dat"));
        System.out.println("entry to file: success");
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null){
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(line);
      }
        BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter("file_2.dat"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error1");
    }
 }
```

Update_1: I took out the Scanner in, changed the while loop, changed OubjectOutputStream to BufferedWriter, and added and if statement. But I still need help getting the program to search for repeated numbers within a phone number that has different ends (240-667-XXXX).

Comment: .dat in no way determines the format of the content, and whether you're doing it correctly depends on what's inside. Also - you're probably going to need regular expressions. Aaand you seem to invoke three different files, only one of which you use in any way

Comment: Deltharis stated that you might need a regular expression and that will be my guess too.  That said, if you do not feel comfortable with regular expression and wish to do more "brute force" you may want to consider replacing `if (line.contains("240-667-"))` with `if (line.startsWith("240-667-"))`, if each line starts with a phone number.

Comment: @Deltharis  so pretty much remove the Scanner in. and put in "Pattern p = Pattern.compile("240-667-") right?

Comment: Sorry for the order in my comment, first things first - get the file reading to work correctly. I don't know what these names signify, but something is definitely not right. Then read up on how regular expressions work, and if you still have problems update the question again (with example .dat file contents since it's important)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which file you are trying to read, 'file_1.dat' or 'inrecords.dat'. I am going to assume its 'file_1.dat'. Then your code should be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader readFile = null;
    try {
        readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "file_1.dat")));
        System.out.println("entry to file: success");
        String line;
        while ((line=readFile.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("240-667-"))
                System.out.println("the line:" + line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    }finally {
        try {
            if (readFile != null)readFile.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at the java documentation for BufferedReader : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: For a full answer it's going to need the `print said codes to another file` part

Comment: @Deltharis     Do you mean the code in program or a clarification. To clarify: search the file containing the codes/numbers of 240-667-XXXX and copy the line in which the codes/numbers sit on and copy it to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

1) You open a file in with a BufferedReader, but you do not read anything from it. Why?

2) You open a file in with a ObjectOutputStream, but you do not write anything in it. Why?
First of all ObjectOutputStream is not the best choice to write Strings.
Better use BufferedWriter
(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/BufferedWriter.html)
If you want to write to another file, you should use the write method in this class.
So create the BufferedWriter BEFORE iterating  and in the loop use the write method to write in the second file.

EDIT:
One more thing. Try to put all the code in a single try{} block. It is a best practice.